# Fade through colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html div and  want the background color to slowly fade through all of the colors.
Example: the div starts at #000000 then goes to #000001 then ..02, ..03 until it gets to #ffffff

Here is the code I have so far

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div>

   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
   height:100px;
   width:100px;
   background-color:#000000;
}
```

Also how could I get it to stop at a different color like #001100

Comment: You realize that's 16 million colors, right? It's going to take a while to go through all of them, since if you want to actually display all of them you have to iterate at the refresh rate of the display or slower.  At a generous 60Hz that's 3.23 days.

Comment: @JimGarrison Oh,  I did not think of that, would going through every fith number work

Comment: @qwertie Just make an array of colors and loop through that. Transition the colors, and you will get the colors in between.

Comment: No, there's no such thing as "every fifth color".  The color is really three components, red, green and blue, packed into a 24-bit integer.  What are you trying to accomplish, and what have you actually tried so far. People on SO generally don't write all your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing something like this on a website I made.

```
//set interval for color change    
setInterval(function(){colorMate();},5000);


//animate body background using color picker function
function colorMate(){
            $('body').animate({backgroundColor: pickColor()},2000);
        }

//declare array of colors to be used when page loads
var colors = ['#206BA4','#BBD9EE','  #EBF4FA','#C0C0C0','#E7E4D3','#F1EFE2','#52ADDA','#68B8DF','#DBDBDB','#AACD4B','#C5AE87'];
var curcolor = 0;

//picks random color from array, different from current one
function pickColor(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    if (rand == curcolor){
        pickColor();
    }
    else { 
        curcolor = rand;
        return colors[rand];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/GtAyC/

Comment: That's because you didn't add jQuery and jQuery-UI, didn't modify the jQuery selector correctly, and I would also move the Javascript into the Javascript field :)

Answer (score 2):

Below is the script that will genrate all the possible color in HTML page

The Loop is quite heavy so there it will take time to execute you can change the parameter of the loop as per as your requirement

I have displayed the output with different div's and each div having different color

These div's are dynamically created and height widht can be changed with css

```
   <html>
   <head>
     <style type='text/css'>
     div{
        height:5px;
        width:5px;
        float:left;
        }
     </style>
   </head>

   <body id='main'  style='width:100%:height:100%;'>
   </body>
      <script  type='text/javascript'>
       /* Loop's Start here */
                            for(x=0;x<225;x++){  // changes the value the parameter to minminze the loop run
                               for(y=0;y<225;y++){                           
                                  for(z=0;z<225;z++){
                                         element = document.createElement("div");  //creating dynamic div
                                         element.id ='id_'+x+'_'+y+'_'+z; //assing id to newly created div
                                         document.body.appendChild(element); // append div to main body
                                         document.getElementById('id_'+x+'_'+y+'_'+z).style.background='rgb('+x+','+y+','+z+')'; //change the color of the div                                       
                                    }
                                }
                            }
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is actually what he was asking for, but that loop is just scary :)

Comment: +1 This actually has a nice effect, although when I ran it I didn't want to loop through every color so I used (`x+=10;y+=10` and `z+=10`).